# Angular Unit test Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a component,
component and page are importing form @bloomreach/spa-sdk

```
  export class ThinComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() component!: BrComponent;
  componentModels: any;
   page: Page;
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentModels = this.component.getModels();  
  }

 getContents(contentRef) {
    if (contentRef && contentRef.$ref) {
      this.content = this.page?.getContent(contentRef).getData();
    }
  }
}
```

and my unit test like

```
  it('should create', () => {
     spyOn(component.component, 'getModels').and.returnValue({foo: 'bar'});
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Throwing and error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getModels')`

Comment: Did you pass anything to `@Input() component` in your unit test? It looks like it is not initialized.

Comment: i am trying to test getContents() 
 component.page = mockPage;
      const content = {
        $ref: 'foo'
      };

      // @ts-ignore
      spyOn(component.page?.getContent('foo'), 'getData').and.callFake( () => {
        return 'test';
      });
But get an error Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getData()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruslan Lekhman is right, you need to initialize the `component` input and I don't think the `spyOn` works for it. `spyOn` only works for public methods.

Try this:

```
it('should create', () => {
     component.component = { getModels: () => ({ foo: 'bar' }) };
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Edit:

Try changing `mockPage` to something like this.

```
const getDataSpy = jasmine.createSpy('getData');
mockPage = { getContent: () => ({ getData: getDataSpy }) };
....
expect(getDataSpy).and.callFake(() => { return 'test'; });
```

Edit

Component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

import { Component as BrComponent, Page } from '@bloomreach/spa-sdk';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  @Input() component!: BrComponent;
  page: Page;
  componentModels: any;
  public content: any;
  public image: string;
  public inViewport = false;
  constructor() {}
  get configuration() {
    return this.component.getParameters();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentModels = this.component?.getModels();
    if (this.componentModels) {
      this.getContents(this.componentModels.document);
    }
  }
  getContents(contentRef) {
    if (contentRef && contentRef.$ref) {
      this.content = this.page?.getContent(contentRef).getData();
      if (this.content) {
        if (this.content.image) {
          this.image = this.getImageUrl(this.content.image);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  getImageUrl($ref): string {
    return this.page.getContent($ref).getUrl();
  }
  onVisible(event) {
    this.inViewport = true;
  }
}
```

Component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './AppComponent';
import { Component as BrComponent, Page } from '@bloomreach/spa-sdk';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.component = {
      getModels: () => ({ document: { $ref: {} } }),
      getParameters: () => ({}),
    };
    component.page = {
      getContent: () => ({
        getData: () => ({ image: 'abc' }),
        getUrl: () => 'xyz',
      }),
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should test ngOninit', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getContents').and.callFake(() => null);
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.getContents).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it('should test getContents', () => {
    component.getContents(component.componentModels.document);
    expect(component.image).toBe('xyz');
  });
});
```

Comment: i am trying to test getContents() component.page = mockPage; const content = { $ref: 'foo' }; // @ts-ignore spyOn(component.page?.getContent('foo'), 'getData').and.callFake( () => { return 'test'; }); But get an error Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getData()

Comment: Check out my edit. I think `spyOn(x, 'methodName')`, x has to be an object and not a method/function like getContent you have shown.

Comment: I tried this
const getDataSpy = jasmine.createSpy('getData');
      getDataSpy.and.returnValue(() => {
        return {image: 'test.png'};
      });
      
      mockPage = { getContent: () => ({ getData: getDataSpy }) };
component.getContents(content);
      expect(component.content.image).toBe('/test.png');
component. content is always undefined

Comment: Can you console.log(component.content), do you get anything out from that?

Comment: it is printing as undefined

Comment: here is the complete file
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1hopeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Where is the `ngOnInit` in the stackblitz? If you don't mind, try pasting your complete `.spec.ts` file and `component.ts` file in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238157/discussion-between-naresh217-and-alif50).