# Update angular from 10.2 to 11. Error - An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Workspace') when run ng test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testbed

This error is returned when running `ng test`
[image]

Find this link - https://lightrun.com/answers/angular-schule-angular-cli-ghpages-cannot-read-property-workspace-of-undefined-after-upgrading-to-angular-v11. But this don't like for my problem

Comment: What version of angular 11 are you using?

Comment: Does this similar question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562611/angular-unit-test-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined ?